# Do we mock a class from a different library imported from nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm fairly new to unit tests. I wanted to know that my method uses a static class from a library imported from nuget package. So it validates a model that was passed and if invalidated it returns back a exception. How do I unit test this? Do I have to mock that static class? It does not have a interface either. So its simply like this Validateblah.Validateblahblah where the first is a class and second is a method

Comment: What benefit would mocking it give you if it were possible? Your code fundamentally behaves on what that other code does, so how would you know it's working as you intend unless you also exercise those other dependencies in your tests? Typically mocks are used to remove dependencies on external factors like the file system/files, databases, external web services, the system clock etc., rather than dependencies on code you didn't write yourself. If it's not difficult to test as it is, then mocking it isn't really needed.

Comment: Agree with points above. Only thing I would add is if you *do* need to mock a static class, you can create your own interface, and then your implementation of that interface would delegate to the static class. Then your classes would depend on that interface instead of the static class, allowing you to mock it for tests. This is how I unit test classes that depend on `DateTime.Now`, for example.